# convert a pandas dataframe subclass into a dataframe object?

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

Can i ask, I'm using someone's (private) code and they have this:

```
class DNATable():
    '''
    A subclass of a Pandas DataFrame, designed to amalgamate data
    easier.
    '''
```

And so the output is this:

```
print(test)
<dnatable.dnatable.DNATable object at 0x7f7162e87fd0>
```

I've tried many ways of converting this to a dataframe, or just doing anything with it, e.g.

```
print(type(pd.DataFrame(test)))
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I also tried returning `test.keys()` to understand if i could make the subclass into a dict, `np.load(test)` to see if I could return arrays and `str(test)` to see it as a string, all of which return similar errors to above saying basically it's not that type of data.

Does someone know how to take an object that's a subclass of a pandas dataframe, and just treat it as a dataframe? (e.g. something like `df = pd.DataFrame(test)`)? Or is it specific to this person's code?

Comment: The real question is whether that class is set up properly and really is a subclass of a pd.DataFrame. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas) go over how to extend the class, and in those cases you _can_ trivially just `pd.DataFrame(DataFrameSubclass)` to get back a normal pandas DataFrame

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough detail to be able to meaningfully answer this question. `DNATable` doesn't seem to inherit from the pandas dataframe class, and we can't see anything about how it is or isn't creating a dataframe "under the hood"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DNATable.__dict__`

Suppose you have this class

```
class DNATable():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self._y = y
        self.__z = z

l = [DNATable(1, 2, 3), DNATable(4, 5, 6)]
```

Create the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i.__dict__ for i in l])
print(df)

# Output
   x  _y  _DNATable__z
0  1   2             3
1  4   5             6
```